# Automapping, duplicate maps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm currently mapping some big objects from an external API to our own objects. This is my first time using Automapper and it works really well.

What I can't seem to find is an option to detect if a mapper is defined twice or more.
Maybe this isn't a problem but I want to prevent the code smell.
It's hard to remember which maps are already created and I don't want to search my code every time I add a mapper.

Also, what are the best practices to organize these profiles? I have multiple profiles already but one profile, related to a big object with nested object 4 layers deep, is already at 70+ lines of `CreateMap<Leg, Contract.V1.Legs.Leg>().ReverseMap();`

It feels like that this is the correct way. But I want to be sure as a newcomer to automapper.

Comment: The default is to throw when a map is defined more than once. Maybe you need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible but have you checked if you can create some rule using ArchUnitNET? It's a amazing library for creating architecture rules as unit tests.

https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnitNET

Edit 1:
About organization. My personal choice is just have all CreateMap calls inside one single file, in alphabetic order, or inside a file per domain when working on a kind of bounded context.

Edit 2:
Found a way to do it with unit tests. AutoMapper configuration provides the AssertConfigurationIsValid that throws for duplicated maps. See below a example using Fluent Assertions:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MapperConfigurationValid()
{
    var configuration = AutoMapperProvider.MapperConfiguration;
    configuration
        .Invoking(c => c.AssertConfigurationIsValid())
        .Should()
        .NotThrow();
}
```